# What are some good Erlang Primers/Tutorials for beginners?

Tags: functional-programming, erlang

What are some good links for diving into Erlang and functional programming in general?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to learn Erlang?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017017/what-is-the-best-way-to-learn-erlang)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's [the first half of Concurrent Programming in Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/download/erlang-book-part1.pdf) [PDF], free.

Answer (score 9):

this might be a good one to look at http://learnyousomeerlang.com/

Answer (score 6):

I think the language itself is surprisingly easy to learn. I recommend http://www.erlang.org/download/getting_started-5.4.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Let me suggest that Erlang is not necessarily typical of "functional programming in general". If you want a good balance, I'd combine reading some of the Erlang-specific sources already cited (or [Joe Armstrong's book, *Programming Erlang: Software for a Concurrent World*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193435600X)) with some of the tutorial links from [the Haskell web site](http://www.haskell.org/).

Comment: why? could you please try to describe what makes it atypical? I'd be very interested in that.