# What is the best way to learn Erlang?

Tags: erlang

Other than specific projects (although those are welcome as well)...

What **tools, books, articles, and other resources** should I have at my desk to help me learn Erlang?

Also, are there mobile runtimes for Erlang?

Please point me in the right direction.

Note: yes, I have visited Erlang and Wikipedia, but I'd like to hear some reliable, experienced opinions.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I'm a month-or-so into learning and the guides I'm enjoying most are:

- The Erlang Site's [Getting Started with Erlang](http://www.erlang.org/doc/getting_started/users_guide.html) Guide
- Joe Armstrong's Book [Software for a Concurrent World](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/jaerlang/programming-erlang) (thoroughly recommended)
- And I have on order: O'Reilly's [Erlang Programming](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596518189/) which has had some really positive reviews and sounds like a good companion to Joe Armstrong's book (covering many of the same topics in greater depth, possibly with more "real world" examples)

I think you can dive into the Getting Started guide straight away and it will certainly give you a feel for functional programming and then concurrency.

If you're in London this June there is the [Erlang Factory](http://www.erlang-factory.com) conference which looks really good.

While I remember, these are two good presentations taking you through Erlang and it's uses:

- [Thinking in Erlang](http://www.scribd.com/doc/44221/Thinking-in-Erlang)
- [Functions + Messages + Concurrency = Erlang](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/joe-armstrong-erlang-qcon08)

Finally, you can follow my learning experiences on my blog ([joelhughes.co.uk/blog](http://www.joelhughes.co.uk/blog)) my step by step adjustment of [FizzBuzz from python/ruby/php to Erlang](http://www.joelhughes.co.uk/blog/2009/05/erlang-fizzbuzz-showdown-pt-1/) might give you a good flavour (sorry about the shameless self promotion).

I have to say learning Erlang is currently one of my greatest pleasures, there is something very satisfying about it!

Comment: Sadly, the FizzBuzz link is broken.

Comment: posterous is no more, is there perhaps new locations to the last 2 links?

Answer (score 38):

For beginners, the "[Learn you some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/)" guide is supremely awesome. It is as of yet incomplete, but provides a lot even with what little is there.

It also has an RSS so you can be informed when (if?) it is updated.

Comment: I found this to be a nice 'quick start guide'.

Comment: This website talks about the nifty gritty detail of Erlang. I prefer tutorials that walk me into building something with Erlang (while introducing those nifty gritty details) step by step on the go.

Answer (score 8):

I found the best thing to do to learn erlang was reading joe's thesis
http://www.sics.se/~joe/thesis/armstrong_thesis_2003.pdf
and then writing something I enjoyed, for me it was an iax2 server.

Answer (score 7):

What I can recommend you is **not** to browse the [*Wings3d* source code](https://github.com/dgud/wings).

(I did it and it was a waste of time similar as when I tried to read the [Quake2 sources](ftp://ftp.idsoftware.com/idstuff/source/quake2.zip) :-p)

Comment: For reference purposes, or if someone is mad enough not to follow your advice, links to sources were added.

Answer (score 4):

I have the both the Erlang Progamming and the Software for a Concurrent World, both are excellent. I might almost say the Erlang Programming is better, it shows a lot more about using OTP (Erlang libraries), but I was also a little more comfortable with the language when I was reading it, so that's what I was looking for.

The Getting Started with Erlang Guide is also pretty good.

Definitely you should give writing a simple server a try. That's one of the areas where Erlang really shines and there's plenty of documentation and tutorials around message passing and the gen_server module.

-- edit

Also, you can run Erlang on ARM based mobile devices (ARMv5+) for sure, you could ask on erlang-questions for other architectures. Check out http://wiki.trapexit.org/index.php/Cross_compiling for the basics of getting started with cross-compiling.