# Learning Erlang

Tags: erlang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to learn Erlang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017017/what-is-the-best-way-to-learn-erlang)

I'm interested in learning Erlang; I'd appreciate suggestions on resources - books, websites, etc. - that can help me along. So far I've learned quite a bit from [Learn you some Erlang.](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/) At this point I'm comfortable with the syntax and most of the (basic) concepts. As a practice project I was thinking of writting a server socket app that serves xml data when conected, unfortunately, I'm not sure where to start - i.e. what libraries to use and how to use them. Thanks.

Comment: Did you look through any of the similar questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=erlang+learning)

Comment: @DOK: Yes, I looked through most of those answers already. While some -["Find some good Erlang Books"-](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789668/finding-some-good-erlang-books) were helpful, none fully addressed my question.

Answer (score 1):

[gen_tcp](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html) is Erlang's interface to TCP/IP sockets. You can find many examples of how to use it in Erlang/OTP libraries or in open-source applications. For example, take a look at these http server and client libraries: https://github.com/mochi/MochiWeb, https://github.com/cmullaparthi/ibrowse

Handling XML in Erlang is more painful than it should be. JSON might be a little bit easier, if you have an option to use it instead of XML.

For XML, there's a standard [Xmerl](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/xmerl/users_guide.html) library which is a part of Erlang/OTP. I found that the least painful way to extract necessary pieces from XML is to use XPath (`xmerl_xpath:string`). For XML generation, `xmerl:export_simple` is the way to go.

I've also used [Erlsom](https://github.com/danw/erlsom) library. I has a (rather) simple XML parsing interface.

Answer (score 0):

trapexit has an excellent article for [building a tcp server with OTP](http://www.trapexit.org/Building_a_Non-blocking_TCP_server_using_OTP_principles).