# Why cannot do I get syntax errors when trying to define functions in Erlang?

Tags: syntax, erlang

I am try to learn Erlang. I've installed a runtime but cannot get it working. The following code:

```
X = 3.
```

works, but none of the following statements work:

```
 f(X)->X.
 F() ->0.
 F([])->[].
```

I get back `1: syntax error before: '->'`. I tried the `word_count` from this [tutorial](http://www.ybrikman.com/writing/2012/11/04/seven-languages-in-seven-weeks-erlang/). And I get the same error.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In REPL you have to use `fun(...) -> ... end`:

```
1> F = fun(X) -> X end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.80484245>
2> F(42).
42
```

If you have code in file use `c` command:

```
1> c(word_count).
{ok,word_count}
2> word_count:word_count([]).
0
```

Comment: Thanks, it works in a console now. But my primary problem was that it does't compile in Eclipse. Even for as simple expression as 
"
Lilo = [5, 3, -3, 0, 0.5] .
Lilo."

I get syntax errors..
I get an error "syntax error before: ':'" in line 

"% lists:filter(fun(X)->X>2, Lilo)." (comment!!)

Comment: In this code example you should split expressions with comma: Lilo = [5, 3, -3, 0, 0.5], Lilo.

Comment: Still the same (note that these expressions are on separate lines, but on Stack Overflow, one cannot place line breaks in a comment.

Comment: OK, I have deleted or the code, saved, and pasted again. Syntax errors are gone, but  shouldn't it display contents of Lilo in a console? This is confusing... I've been using F# so far and thought that a switch to Erlang wouldn't be such a big deal :/

Comment: OK, I get it. For some reason Eclipse doesn't automatically 'c(lilo)'. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is difference in sytax when writing functions in Erlang module and Erlang shell (REPL). As P_A mentioned you need to call as `F = fun(X) -> X end, F("Echo").`

Also note that function names are atoms so has to start with lowercase when you are writing in Erlang module. If you are serious about learning Erlang I would suggest you go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017017/what-is-the-best-way-to-learn-erlang).

You mentioned that you worked on F#. The basic difference between F# and Erlang in this case is that expression 
`let Lilo = [|5; 3; -3; 0; 0.5|];;` Can be written directly in the file and executed. In Erlang it can only be done in Erlang shell and not inside a file.
So the expression you are trying should be inside a function inside a [module](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/modules.html) with the same name as file. Consider test.erl file. Any function you export can be called from outside (shell).

```
-module(test).    
-export([test/0]).    
test() ->
    Lilo = [5, 3, -3, 0, 0.5],
    [X*2 || X <-Lilo].
```