# How to Create and Array and For Loop In Erlang

Tags: erlang

How do you:

- Create an integer array
- Create a For Loop
- Modify Elements

Comment: Sounds like you should read through an Erlang tutorial.

Comment: Need a good tutorial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375827/what-are-some-good-erlang-primers-tutorials-for-beginners

Answer (score 2):

starting here would be a good idea: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real

all of your questions will be answered, but it may not be the "quick answer" you where looking for